# Call a function inside a class when calling the class in python

Tags: python, function, class

This simple example is what I dont get to work or understand in my more complex script:

```
class printclass():
    string="yes"
    def dotheprint(self):
        print self.string
    dotheprint(self)
printclass()
```

When the class is called, I expected it to run the function, but instead it will tell me that "self is not defined". Im aware this happens on the line:

```
dotheprint(self)
```

But I dont understand why. What should I change for the class to run the function with the data it already has within? (string)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You misunderstand how classes work. You put your call inside the class definition body; there is no instance at that time, there is no `self`.

Call the method on the instance:

```
instance = printclass()
instance.dotheprint()
```

Now the `dotheprint()` method is bound, there is an instance for `self` to refer to.

If you need `dotheprint()` to be called when you create an instance, give the class an `__init__` method. This method (the initializer) is called whenever you create an instance:

```
class printclass():
    string="yes"

    def __init__(self):
        self.dotheprint()

    def dotheprint(self):
        print self.string

printclass()
```

Answer (score 1):

You really need to understand Object-Oriented Programming and its implementation in Python.
You cannot "call" a class like any function. You have to create an instance, which has a lifetime and methods linked to it:

```
o = printclass() # new object printclass
o.dotheprint()   #
```

A better implementation of your class:

```
class printclass():
    string="yes"         #beware, this is instance-independant (except if modified later on)

    def dotheprint(self):
        print self.string

    def __init__(self):  # it's an initializer, a method called right after the constructor
         self.dotheprint()
```

Comment: `__init__` is not a constructor. It doesn't construct instances. It is an initializer; it is called *after* the item has been constructed already. `__new__` is the constructor.

Comment: oh you're right. Since the aren't any memory management in Python, I hardly use __new__. I'll fix my answer.